# merging some entries in a python list based on length of items

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of about `20-30` items [`strings`].

I'm able to print them out in my program just fine - but I'd like to save some space, and merge items that are shorter...

So basically, if I have `2 consecutive items` that the combined lengths are less than 30, I want to join those to items as a single entry in the list - with a `/` between them

I'm not coming up with a simple way of doing this.

I don't care if I do it in the same list, or make a new list of items...  it's all happening inside 1 `function`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the list and keep joining items till they satisfy your requirement (size 30). Then add them to a new list when an element grows that big.

```
l=[] # your new list
buff=yourList[0] if len(yourList)>0 else "" # hold strings till they reach desired length
for i in range(1,len(yourList)):
    # check if concatenating will exceed the size or not
    t=yourList[i]
    if (len(buff) + len(t) + 1) <= 30:
        buff+="/"+t
    else:
        l.append(buff)
        buff=t
l.append(buff) # since last element is yet to be inserted
```

Comment: while this is close, the problem with your solution is my first item would be "/item" or "" as buff would be empty and appended if my first item was over 30.  I sort of had that idea myself...   was just being clunky...

Answer (score 0):

You can `extend` method of list as follows:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

a.append('/')
a.extend(b)
```

You just need to check the size of two list `a and b` as per your requirements.

I hope I understood your problem !

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, you can check to see if that's what you wanted, it's a bit lenghty but it works.

```
list1 = yourListOfElements
for elem in list1: 
    try: # Needs try/except otherwise last iteration would throw an indexerror
        listaAUX = [] # Auxiliar list to check length and join smaller elements. You can probably eliminate this using list slicing
        listaAUX.append(elem)
        listaAUX.append(list1[list1.index(elem)+1])
        if len(listaAUX[0]) + len(listaAUX[1]) < 30:
            concatenated = '/'.join(listaAUX)
            print(concatenated)
        else:
            print(elem)
    except IndexError:
        print(elem)
```

Comment: Not quite - I have a separate function that is printing - so I need a single list when it's all said and done to pass into the function...